# I want to show marker on google map like the attached image

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

[image: Attached image of map]

I want to show my current position marker icon like to the attached image.

Comment: check this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/how-to-create-a-custom-shaped-bitmap-marker-with-android-map-api-v2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Custom marker icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077494/android-custom-marker-icon)

Comment: @KoratPrakash Thanks, it means this is an image. This not from google map, right???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to add your custom marker to map

```
 mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
  .position(LATLONG)          
  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(R.drawable.yourIcon))));
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamad Rostani, I know how to use custom marker, I  just want to know that this is our custom icon or it come from google map.

Comment: which one do you mean?

Comment: The circle icon

Comment: that small circle icon is google maps default icon. and the highlighted circle comes when the location is not very accurate.

Comment: thats google maps default bro. but maybe you could change the shape

Comment: thats true. take a look at this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786552/how-to-implement-current-location-blue-icon-in-here-map/45138088

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180987/discussion-between-mohamad-rostami-and-rakesh-kushwaha).